# Apache 2.4.2 (win32), mod_fcgid - Can't find module file

Tags: apache2, mod-fcgid

(lastest fcgid module)
OS: Windows Xp prof SP3

I place file mod_fcgid.so in directory (modules)

// Httpd.conf

```
    LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
```

But. When i try run http (from cmd  - for test purpose)
I get error:

```
    httpd: Syntax error on line 515 of C:/Core/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load
    C:/Core/Apache24/modules/mod_fcgid.so into server: Nie mo\xbfna odnale\x9f\xe6
    okre\x9clonego modu\xb3u.
```

Path is correct. So what is bad?

Answer (score 1):

[This link may help.](http://www.devside.net/guides/config/windows/httpd-conf) Here's an example of correct syntax:

```
IfDefine FCGI
    LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
IfDefine
```

Answer (score 0):

- Kindly visit https://www.apachelounge.com/download/
- Download zip folder named **mod_fcgid**
- Copy&Paste **mod_fcgid.so** file in your apache modules folder
- Remember to load in your **httd.conf** file => ***LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so***